# Brightcove Videos in Indonesia

Tags: cordova, video, brightcove

I'm having issues playing Brightcove videos in a Cordova app in Indonesia, being based in UK I can't replicate the issue so having trouble identifying the problem, hoping for help from someone who has encountered this issue.

I have a mobile app that shows users Brightcove hosted videos as they allow videos to be played in Indonesia without needing a VPN. However, on distribution to Indonesia the videos aren't working, but do work in Europe. The videos don't appear to be generating an error message, the iframe that the videos are loaded into just has a blackbackground with a white spinner (Brightcove styling/functionality not the app).

In an attempt to debug the issue, there is a test video on Brightcove's homepage which works on the Indonesian mobile device in a browser.

The code for showing the video to the user is as below,

```html
<iframe
 webkitallowfullscreen
 mozallowfullscreen
 allowfullscreen
 src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/123456789?title=0&amp;autoplay=0&amp;badge=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0">
</iframe>
```

Is there any setting in Brightcove that needs to be tweaked to allow these videos to work, or have I missed something really obvious?

Thanks in advance,

Áine

Comment: That's a Vimeo player

Comment: yeah, is that wrong then?

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs because the Indonesian government has banned Vimeo indefinitely since around 2014.